# Describing the Kernel of a map from The Fundamental Group to the integers

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, algebraic-topology

If my group is the fundamental group with genus $g$ of surfaces

$S_g=⟨a_1,b_1,…,a_g,b_g\mid[a_1,b_1]...[a_g,b_g]=1⟩ $

and I have a map $H$ from my group to the integers:

$H: S_g\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$

such that $a_1$ goes to $1$ and all other elements go to zero, how do I write the kernel?

I know that everything except $a_1$ is in the kernel obviously but in this case

$a_1b_1a_1^{-1}$ would be $1+0-1=0$

so this is in the kernel as well, along with anything else that combines elements in a similar way. So I know the kernel is infinite, but how do I write it mathematically?

Comment: where does it $a_1^2$ go?

Comment: a1^2 = a1+a1 = 1+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess, you mean all other *generators*, i.e. $b_1,a_2,\dots,b_q$, by 'all other elements' and 'everything except $a_1$'.

In your equation with $1-0+1$, the element $a_1$ can be replaced by any element of the group: $H(xb_1x^{-1})=0$. That is - such as every kernel - $\,\ker H$ will be a *normal subgroup*. 
Specifically, it is the normal subgroup $N$ generated by $b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots,a_q,b_q$.

> Assume that $w\in S_g$ is in the kernel, take a represantative word and group together anything that is not $a_1$, obtaining $w=x_0a_1^{t_1}x_1a_1^{t_2}\dots$ with $t_i\in\Bbb Z$ and $x_i\in N$. Then the assumption implies $\sum_it_i=0$. Finally, bring all $a_1^{t_i}$ to e.g. leftmost, by exchanging like $\ x_0a_1^{t_1}=a_1^{t_1}(\underbrace{a_1^{-t_1}x_0a_1^{t_1}}_{y_0})\ $ where $y_0$ is also in $N$.

Comment: A1 and b1 do not commute. You misread the relations.

Comment: Ahh.. indeed. Thanks.

Comment: So how would I write it in the normal way to describe a set such as ker = {x in H | f(x)=0}? In the end I want to be able to compare the number of elements in the kernel to the number of elements in the origin because I was told that although they are both infinite, supposedly the kernel is “more infinite” than the origin

Comment: This is a normal way: "$\ker H$ is the normal subgroup of $S_g$ generated by $b_1,a_2,b_2,\dots,a_q,b_q$". Do you want the (size of the) quotient group $S_g/N$?

Comment: Yes I would like to know the size in this case thank you

Comment: Well, the quotient is still infinite, it will be isomorphic to $\Bbb Z$ by the first isomorphism theorem (the closets are presicely $a_1^kN$ with $k\in\Bbb Z$).

Comment: @Berci can you explain why the elements $x_i$ are in $N$

Comment: By hypothesis. We write $w$ as a product of $a_i^{t_i} $ and $b_i^{s_i} $. Then every term is either in $N$ or is of the form  $a_1^t$.

Comment: @Berci So I now know that the kernel can be described as a free group with infinite generators. My new question is how to show that there are no relations between the generators. What I mean is how can I prove that all of the generators are unique?

Comment: I'm not sure it's a free group..

Comment: @Berci: It is free, see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/18454/fundamental-groups-of-noncompact-surfaces